# Best way to orchestrate a series of near-identical builds on the same hardware

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to test OS builds on bare metal via Jenkins.
Right now I've got as series of 60 or so jobs (monthly builds * 3 OSes * 1 job for build and one for validation) multiplied by 10 or so hosts, each set of ten chained in a loop.
This is...unwieldy to say the least.
I'm trying to use Jenkins Pipeline to cut this down - and I'd prefer to only kick off the first build when any of several git repos that are relevant change, but then I'd like to have them cascade.

I have tried a loop in my jenkinsfile, but then if any individual stage fails all the stages after fail.
What do you suggest?

My current "plan" is to have 1 project per OS version per host, and parameterize the "watch upstream" for each. This still seems like more hassle than it's worth.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  options {
    ansiColor('xterm')
  }
  //properties([
    //pipelineTriggers([
    //  [$class: "SCMTrigger", scmpoll_spec: "H/5 * * * *"],
    //])
  //])
  stages {
    stage ('Checkout Build Script') {
      steps {
        checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
        branches: [[name: '*/master']],
        extensions: [],
        userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'xxx', url: 'xxx/host_rebuild.git']]])
      }
    }
    stage ("Build Test OS") {
      steps {
        sh """./build.py -H ${TARGET_HOST} -p ${PROFILE}"""
        archiveArtifacts allowEmptyArchive: true, artifacts: 'messages,anamon,ipaclient,hardware_info,firmware_info', caseSensitive: true, defaultExcludes: true, fingerprint: false, onlyIfSuccessful: false
      }
    }
    stage ('Checkout Validation Code') {
      steps {
        checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
+------  3 lines: branches: [[name: 'master']],-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ])
      }
    } 
    stage ("Validate OS") {
      steps {
        sh """kinit  xxx.COM -k -t /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/xxx.keytab"""
        withEnv(["TARGET_OS=${MAJ_OS}", "TARGET_HOST=${TARGET_HOST}"]){
          sh """rake spec"""
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Attempt at explaining the "short" form:
I want to run a series of projects using a non-concurrent object (a remote bare-metal host) one after the other. I want each one to be triggered by the one before it. I want to use declarative pipeline. 
I want the subsequent projects to run regardless of the end state of the previous project.
I would prefer the first project to be triggered by an SCM check.
I would prefer all jobs to use the same jenkinsfile.

Is this possible?

Comment: e.g. I'd love to use this, but I want to iterate over a set of variables rather than have a single one over and over: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand correctly your issue, however - how about using the `parallel` directive? You can configure it to failFast or keep running till all parallel jobs finished. Also, if you want to run all serialized, you can prevent early exit by `try catch` constructs (Edit: or `sh step with returnStatus, see [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script))and saving the build status in some temp variable(or array) and evaluate at the end.

Comment: unfortunately it seems that I haven't done a good job of explaining.

Going to try again in the question